# ¿Hallar la media entre un intervalo de enteros de una lista de enteros de un fichero en C++?

Tags: c++

Utilizando solo C++ y no C, y programando para Linux,
dispongo de un archivo *binario* que contiene una serie de registros de personas con secuencia: *nombre edad nombre edad (...)* (donde nombre = char [30] y edad = int).
Lo que tengo que hacer es pedir al usuario 2 nombres que presuponemos que sabe que constan en el registro (no pide comprobarlo) y entonces obtener la edad de todas las personas que se encuentran ubicadas en el registro entre las dos personas dadas y hacer con ellas la media.

Es decir, si en el archivo hay:
Pepito 34 Jaimito 28 Fulanito 30 Manganita 32 Federico 29
y el usuario introduce Jaimito y Manganita, el programa debe obtener las edades de Jaimito, Fulanito y Manganita, sumarlas y dividirlas por 3 y devolver el resultado.

Esto es en el marco de un ejercicio mas amplio en el que he creado yo la estructura de Personas (struct-array global) con sus datos y creado el archivo binario en donde las he registrado, realizando otras tareas que sí supe hacer. Lo comento porque vengo accediendo de este modo en cada función:

```
Persona pers;   
    int edad;

    ifstream archivo("datosej3.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);

        archivo.read(reinterpret_cast< char * > (&pers), sizeof(Persona));

        while(archivo && !archivo.eof()){
```

Con eso he podido, por ejemplo, mostrar solo registros que tengan una edad dada por el usuario.
Pero no se cómo hacer lo que me pide esta vez sobre la media entre registros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que los nombres te los mandan como parametros (argv), prueba a hacer lo siguiente:

```
Persona pers;   
    int suma=0;
    int cuenta=0;
    bool primero_encontrado=false;

    ifstream archivo("datosej3.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
    while(archivo.read((char*)&pers, sizeof(Persona))){
        if (!primero_encontrado && !strcmp(pers.nombre,argv[1]))
            primero_encontrado=true;
        if (primero_encontrado) {
            suma+=pers.edad;
            cuenta++;
        }
        if (primero_encontrado && !strcmp(pers.nombre,argv[2]))
            break;
    }
    if (cuenta>0) {
        double media=(double)suma/cuenta;
        cout << media;
    }
```

Comment: No me los mandan como argv por terminal al inicio sino que los pido yo mismo en la función con cout y me los entran por teclado con cin a variables que yo creo para el caso (char nombre1[30],...). Pero eso no es problema, simplemente cambio argv por nombre1 y argv2 por nombre2 y está funcionando perfecto, gracias, disculpad que no haya sido claro indicando cómo recibía los datos.